# Where does the Bible talk about marriage to non-Christians?

Tags: marriage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are inter-faith marriages prohibited by the Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1611/are-inter-faith-marriages-prohibited-by-the-bible)

1st & 2nd Corinthians speak of how Christians should not be "unequally yolked" in marriage to non-Christians.

**Where else does the Bible talk about marriage to non-Christians?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The history of the Israelites from the period of Joshua through the Kings is one big warning about intermarrying with other peoples.

- Joshua adjures the people not to let any men, women, or children in Canaan survive, lest they be a temptation.  (Indeed, Rahab is singled out *not* to be killed* as the exception.)
- Solomon is chastised for taking concubines from other lands
- Jezebel, the wife of Ahab is a constant source of temptation to go to other gods, especially Baal.
- Ruth is seen as extraordinary, being a Moabite, but nonetheless willing to become a Jew for inclusion in the promise.

In every case during this period where foreign wives are mentioned, it is considered a bad thing. Only where foreign wives are willing to drop their identity and join the people of the Land is it ever commended in Scripture.

Comment: Yes, I'm obviously talking about marriage to non-*Jews* here, but the point is still that the people of the promise are discouraged from syncretism.